# How can I set Cache TTL for my font files with htacces?

Tags: joomla-4.x, google

My site is very good I think in pagespeed

https://www.glansbeton.be

But I have a problem with my 2 fonts

https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-glansbeton-be/l7cuaewka9?form_factor=mobile

The cache TTL is now none, how can I make this to for example one year?